# how to telnet huawei switch with python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to telnet huawei switch with python script to read some basic staff like "display int brief" result. I know basic huawei command and some programming.
I can telnet cisco router with python script.

Here is my attempt so far

```
import telnetlib 
import datetime 

now = datetime.datetime.now() 
host = "myhost" # your router ip 
username = "user" # the username 
password = "pass" 

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host,23,6) 
tn.read_until("Username:") 
tn.write(username+"\n") 
tn.read_until("Password:") 
tn.write(password+"\n") 
tn.write("display int description"+"\n") 
#tn.write("sh run"+"\n") 
tn.write("quit"+"\n") 
output = tn.read_all() 

fp = open("sw_hu.txt","w") 
fp.write(output) 
fp.close()
```

Comment: You will need to give more information, your question is lacking detail and so is not clear and also too broad to get an answer. You have [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/telnetlib.html) in the standard library, so that will be a good place to start and you can post some more specific questions when you run into issues.

Comment: I have added my script to describe my expectation.

Comment: ok well how does your code fail and what did you do differently for the cisco router. Sometimes routers have older versions of the server and the same code doesn't work for them.

Comment: the same script worked in cisco. I only changed  commands  "display int description"  to "show int brief" and "quit" to "exit"

Comment: Each device may require different commands.  Attempt a telnet session from the terminal and figure out the commands you need to issue. Ultimately your code may need to vary the commands it issues depending the device.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library then open connection with `pexpect.spawn('telnet ip_address')` module documentation is great start. If you now commands then it is mostly combination off `sendline`, `expect` and `before`.

```
    child = pexpect.spawn ('telnet %s' % dev_name)
    try:
        i = child.expect_exact(['Password:', 'Username:'])
    except (pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT):
        return False
    if i == 1:
        child.sendline(user_name)
        child.expect_exact('Password:')
        child.sendline(passw)
    else:
        child.sendline(passw)
        if child.expect_exact(['>', 'Wrong', pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout=5):
            child.close()
            return False
        child.sendline('sup')
        i = child.expect_exact(['Password:', '>', 'Unknown', 'not set'])
        if i == 1:
            child.sendline('')
        elif i == 2 or i == 3:
            child.close()
            return False
        else:
            child.sendline(ena)
    if child.expect_exact(['>', 'Password', 'failed']):
        child.close()
    child.sendline('tftp %s put %s %s.backup.txt' % (TFTP, conf_name, name))
    child.expect_exact(['>', 'successfully'])
    if 'Unable' in child.before:
        .... 
        ....
```

Edit: Added partial example to backup config (it is python 2.x and old Huawei router)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if  w['router_type'] == "cisco":
        tn.read_until("Username:")
        tn.write(user.encode('ascii')+"\n"
            #tn.write(user +"\n")
        if password:
            tn.read_until("Password:")
            tn.write(password.encode("ascii") + "\n")(indent)
            tn.write("terminal length 0\n")
            tn.write("show version\n")
            tn.write("show running-config view full\n")
            tn.write("exit\n")
            tn_output = tn.read_all()
            print ("Logging out Router ") + w['host_name'] + ("_") + w['router_type'] + (".....")
            flag = 1


    if  w['router_type'] == "huawei":
        tn.read_until("Username:")
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        if password:
            tn.read_until("Password:")
            tn.write(password + "\n")
            tn.write("screen-length 0 temporary\n")
            tn.write("dis version\n")
            tn.write("dis current-configuration\n")
            tn_output = tn.read_until("return")
            tn.write("quit\n")
            print ("Logging out Router ") + w['host_name'] + ("_") + w['router_type'] + (".....")
            flag = 1


    if  w['router_type'] == "MAIPU":
        tn.read_until("login:")
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        if password:
            tn.read_until("password:")
            tn.write(password + "\n")           
            tn.write("more off\n")
            tn.write("show version\n")
            tn.write("show running\n")
            tn.write("logout\n")
            tn_output = tn.read_all()
            flag = 1
            print ("Logging out Router ") + w['host_name'] + ("_") + w['router_type'] + (".....")
    print ("\n Count: " )+ str(v_count) + ("---\n")
    if flag:
        if v_count==0:
            saveoutput = open ("BACKUP/" + HOST + ".txt" , "w")
            saveoutput.write(tn_output)
            print ("Saving new file ") + HOST + ("......")
        elif v_count == 1:
            previous_file = open("BACKUP/" + HOST + ".txt")
            temp_file = previous_file.read()

            if str(temp_file) != str(tn_output):
            saveoutput = open ("BACKUP/" + HOST + "_v2.txt" , "w")
                saveoutput.write(tn_output)`enter code here`
                print ("Saving new file " )+ HOST + ("......")
        elif v_count > 1:
            previous_file = open("BACKUP/" + HOST + "_v" + str(v_count) + ".txt")
            temp_file = previous_file.read()

                if str(temp_file) != str(tn_output):
    saveoutput = open ("BACKUP/" + HOST + "_v" + str(v_count + 1)  + ".txt" , "w")
        print ("Saving new version of file ") + HOST + ("......")`enter code here`
```

Comment: can you please edit your answer with the explanation that you can give to make it understandable?